# How to club values according to their ids and Financial Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**I am having data in a table like this**

**id              fy1              int1             fy2             int2             fy3             int3**
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

1       2013 - 2014       9167       2014 - 2015       1183       2015 - 2016       3002 
1       2013 - 2014       10744       2014 - 2015       1345       2015 - 2016       2709
1       2014 - 2015       1758       2015 - 2016       2347

I want to club the interest where FY matches corresponding to particular ID.

**I want my data to be in the form as shown below ** 


**id              fy1              int1             fy2             int2             fy3             int3**
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

1       2013 - 2014       19911       2014 - 2015       4286       2015 - 2016       8058

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,fy1,SUM(int1) as int1,fy2,SUM(int2) as int2,fy3,SUM(int3) as int3
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id,fy1,fy2,fy3
```

Comment: I have already tried the same thing but its not giving me the result which I wanted. Its not clubing the results according to FY. In 3 row FY1 '2014-2015' is 1758 I want it to get clubbed with the FY2 of Row 1 and Row 2 '2014-2015' which are 1183 and 1345. So, I want my final result of FY2 '2014-2015' = 4286. And same in case of other '2015-2016'